# Accessing struct array outside function

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

..C..
I am trying to figure out how to access my filled array which utilizes a struct with another function which I will use later for sorting, but I can't even print my function that filled the array in my main.

I have loaded the function inside main which works and printing inside the fillArray function works but I will need to access the array from outside the function later on for a bubble sort and a binary search.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 100

typedef struct Person
{
    char firstname[25];
    char lastname[25];
} person;

person list [SIZE];

person loadPeople(char firstname[25],char lastname[25])
{
    person p;
    strcpy(p.firstname, firstname);
    strcpy(p.lastname,  lastname);
    return p;
}

void fillArray()
{
    list[0] = loadPeople("Bob","Baker");
    list[1] = loadPeople("Bill","Johnson");
    list[2] = loadPeople("John","Finmeister");
    list[3] = loadPeople("Jennifer","Ratblaster");
    list[4] = loadPeople("Shaun","Gares");
    list[5] = loadPeople("Diggy","McDigMaster");
    list[6] = loadPeople("Joanne","TheStore");
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

    printf("First homie's name is: %s %s\n",list[0].firstname,list[0].lastname);

    return 0;
}
```

I just want to print from main recalling from fillArray but right now it only prints:

First homie's name is:

thats it

Comment: You need to call `fillArray()` before trying to read data from the array.

Comment: Your definition of main() is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `fillArray()` in order to execute it:

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    fillArray();
    printf("First homie's name is: %s %s\n",list[0].firstname,list[0].lastname);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `main()` should only have two parameters as shown here.